# Adam & Eve after Alien invasion

Tags: story-identification, aliens

Read a book when I was a kid, I’M sure it was called Adam & Eve and then a Date, it followed the journey of a man and women after an Alien invasion, oddly the only bit of story I can remember was the girl teaching the Alien children how to make straw hats, oh and that the cover had a naked man and woman on it (like I said I was a kid!)

Answer (score 6):

Probably [Adam and Eve 2020 A.D.](https://www.isfdb.org/cgi-bin/title.cgi?1244445) by Paul Blackden as you can see from the [distinctive cover](https://m.popkey.co/caa52b/JL006.gif) below.

> Young Terry couldn't explain the ominous whispering in the sky. Or the terror in his father and mother.
> Then comes the televised panic in New York. In London. In old York. All over.
> Followed by black devastation.
> And yet he survives. So does Jackie, the new-age girl.
> Together they face the Great Machine and the Evil People.
> Just He and She.
> They trust in destiny. And luck.
> They seek to avoid their future being destroyed in an ash-smothered farewell to the world we know.
> Together.
> The new Adam and Eve.

[image]

Comment: ... >_< I don't want to admit how much time I spent looking for a title along the lines of "Adan & Eve and a Date"...

Comment: @FuzzyBoots - I spent precisely ten seconds doing [a search on ISFDB for titles containing "Adam" and "Eve"](http://www.isfdb.org/cgi-bin/adv_search_results.cgi?USE_1=title_title&OPERATOR_1=contains&TERM_1=Adam&CONJUNCTION_1=AND&USE_2=title_title&OPERATOR_2=contains&TERM_2=Eve&CONJUNCTION_2=AND&USE_3=title_title&OPERATOR_3=exact&TERM_3=&ORDERBY=title_title&START=0&TYPE=Title) then scrolling down. I then copied the (only) two matches into google images. In fairness, I also spent several minutes trying to find the Minions gif where they laugh about bottoms.

Comment: ^_^ Yeah. I did about the same thing, except I skipped over the title you mention because I was specifically looking for the text of "Adam & Eve and then a Date" :-P The lack of boundaries on the title and the capitalization of "Date" confused me.

Comment: @Valorum - There are dozens. If you found the one you're looking for, the polite thing to do would be link it. Minions are the best.

Comment: @JohnP - If you look closely at the answer above, you'll be in for a big surprise